# searching video from Youtube channel which are uploaded only in that channel depending on the video Name

Tags: c#, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-dotnet-client, youtube-channels

I am trying to search the video which is present in my channel only based upon the video name of the particular video. However when I tried the following code, I am seeing all the videos that are present in YouTube related to the search keyword. I want to fetch only the videos that are present in my channel.
Using all the required latest library

**Code is here**

```
    private async Task Run()
    {
      var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
      {
        ApiKey = "My API Key ",//"REPLACE_ME",
        ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
      });

      var searchListRequest = youtubeService.Search.List("snippet");
      searchListRequest.Q = "MYVID"; // Replace with your search term.
      searchListRequest.MaxResults = 50;

      // Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified query term.
      var searchListResponse = await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

      List<string> videos = new List<string>();
      List<string> channels = new List<string>();
      List<string> playlists = new List<string>();

      // Add each result to the appropriate list, and then display the lists of
      // matching videos, channels, and playlists.
      foreach (var searchResult in searchListResponse.Items)
      {
        switch (searchResult.Id.Kind)
        {
          case "youtube#video":
            videos.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.VideoId));
            break;

          case "youtube#channel":
            channels.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.ChannelId));
            break;

          case "youtube#playlist":
            playlists.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.PlaylistId));
            break;
        }
      }

      Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Videos:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", videos)));
      Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Channels:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", channels)));
      Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Playlists:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", playlists)));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list), you can use the 'channelId' parameter in search request.

```
searchListRequest.ChannelId = {YOUR_CHANNEL_ID};
```

(I'm not a c# person. Please check the attribute name)